# Geofence Not Use Continuous Updated Coordinate

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-alarms, android-geofence

I had created a tracking apps using **Firebase**. The apps have **2 type user log in user's** (driver & parent) with **different** layout and different task.

Driver user will updated their location on Firebase database **continuously** into their own root of their tree.

Parent user will **retrieve the data continuousl**y to be shown on map layout and geofence layout as a **latlng** for the **geofence coordinate**.

My problem is on the geofence activity. The button 'Start Geofence' will toast *" Geofence Successfully Added "* and it is done perfectly. But when I click the button, its seems to get the value of **latlng** only **static position** while the data are **continuously updated** according to the Driver user's location.

I have done testing on **mock situation**. My friends log in as driver and drive from location A to location B **(my location)** and I log in as parent to track my friends location. When I **click** 'Start Geofence' button, the text *" Geofence Successfully Added "* are successfully toasted. But my geofence alarm **not trigerred** when my friends are near to location B. But **when I click again, the alarm are triggered**.

I assume that my geofence only take the **CURRENT** latlng data when I **press/click** the button 'Start Geofence', not continuously get updated latlng data from Firebase Database.

Can someone explain me why?

I need to use the location of the driver as my geofence coordinate, so it will be a moving geofence.

Here my **ParentsActivity.java**

```
public class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ValueEventListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, ResultCallback<Status> {

private static final String TAG = "ParentActivity";
private Button btnTrack, btnGeofence, signout;

private FirebaseAuth auth;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

private Location lastLocation;
double lat;
double lng;
LatLng latLng;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(ParentActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("yKlWu19vhqQXfL2tDlBNfMSduMe2");


    // set the view now
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_parent);

    btnTrack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_track);
    btnGeofence = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_geo);
    signout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out);


    btnTrack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ParentActivity.this, MapsActivity.class));
        }
    });

    signout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            auth.signOut();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(ParentActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    });

    btnGeofence.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startGeofence();

        }
    });

    createGoogleApi();


}

@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    lat = dataSnapshot.child("location/latitude").getValue(Double.class);

    lng = dataSnapshot.child("location/longitude").getValue(Double.class);



    latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);



}

// Create GoogleApiClient instance
private void createGoogleApi() {
    Log.d(TAG, "createGoogleApi()");
    if ( googleApiClient == null ) {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder( this )
                .addConnectionCallbacks( this )
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener( this )
                .addApi( LocationServices.API )
                .build();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(this);
    googleApiClient.connect();


}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();

}

// GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks connected
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onConnected()");
    getLastKnownLocation();
}

private void getLastKnownLocation() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getLastKnownLocation()");
    if ( checkPermission() ) {
        lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        if ( lastLocation != null ) {
            Log.i(TAG, "LasKnown location. " +
                    "Long: " + lastLocation.getLongitude() +
                    " | Lat: " + lastLocation.getLatitude());
            startLocationUpdates();
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "No location retrieved yet");
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }
    else askPermission();
}

private LocationRequest locationRequest;
// Defined in mili seconds.
// This number in extremely low, and should be used only for debug
private final int UPDATE_INTERVAL =  1000 * 60;
private final int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 30;

// Start location Updates
private void startLocationUpdates(){
    Log.i(TAG, "startLocationUpdates()");
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
            .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

    if ( checkPermission() )
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged ["+location+"]");
    lastLocation = location;
}


// Check for permission to access Location
private boolean checkPermission() {
    Log.d(TAG, "checkPermission()");
    // Ask for permission if it wasn't granted yet
    return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED );
}

// Asks for permission
private void askPermission() {
    Log.d(TAG, "askPermission()");
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            new String[] { android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
            100
    );
}

// Verify user's response of the permission requested
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult()");
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch ( requestCode ) {
        case 100: {
            if ( grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
                // Permission granted
                getLastKnownLocation();

            } else {
                // Permission denied
                permissionsDenied();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

// App cannot work without the permissions
private void permissionsDenied() {
    Log.w(TAG, "permissionsDenied()");
}



// GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks suspended
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended()");
}

// GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener fail
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionFailed()");
}

private static final long GEO_DURATION = 60 * 60 * 1000;
private static final String GEOFENCE_REQ_ID = "My Geofence";
private static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 300; // in meters



// Create a Geofence
private Geofence createGeofence(double latitude, double longitude, float radius ) {
    Log.d(TAG, "createGeofence");
    return new Geofence.Builder()
            .setRequestId(GEOFENCE_REQ_ID)
            .setCircularRegion( latitude, longitude, radius)
            .setExpirationDuration( GEO_DURATION )
            .setTransitionTypes( Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER
                    | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT )
            .build();
}

// Create a Geofence Request
private GeofencingRequest createGeofenceRequest( Geofence geofence ) {
    Log.d(TAG, "createGeofenceRequest");
    return new GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger( GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER )
            .addGeofence( geofence )
            .build();
}


private final int GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE = 0;
private PendingIntent createGeofencePendingIntent() {

    Intent intent = new Intent( this, GeofenceTransitionIntentService.class);
    return PendingIntent.getService(this, GEOFENCE_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
}

// Add the created GeofenceRequest to the device's monitoring list
private void addGeofence(GeofencingRequest request) {
    Log.d(TAG, "addGeofence");
    if (checkPermission())
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                googleApiClient,
                request,
                createGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onResult: " + status);
    if ( status.isSuccess() ) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GEOFENCE SUCCESSFUL ADDED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;// inform about fail
    }
}

// Start Geofence creation process
private void startGeofence() {
    Log.i(TAG, "startGeofence()");
    Geofence geofence = createGeofence(lat, lng, GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS );
    GeofencingRequest geofenceRequest = createGeofenceRequest( geofence );
    addGeofence( geofenceRequest );

}
```

Here my **GeofenceIntentService.java**

```
public class GeofenceTransitionIntentService extends IntentService {
private static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitionIS";


public GeofenceTransitionIntentService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Log.i(TAG, "onHandleIntent");

    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
        //String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
        //      geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
        Log.e(TAG, "Goefencing Error " + geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
        return;
    }

    // Get the transition type.
    int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

    Log.i(TAG, "geofenceTransition = " + geofenceTransition + " Enter : " + Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER + "Exit : " + Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT);
    if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER || geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL){
        showNotification("Entered", "Entered the Location");
        playAlarm();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Van Nearby", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Showing Notification...");
        showNotification("Exited", "Exited the Location");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Van Exited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        // Log the error.
        showNotification("Error", "Error");
        Log.e(TAG, "Error ");
    }
}

public void showNotification(String text, String bigText) {

    // 1. Create a NotificationManager
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // 2. Create a PendingIntent for AllGeofencesActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ParentActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // 3. Create and send a notification
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon_a)
            .setContentTitle("Notification!")
            .setContentText(text)
            .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(bigText))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}

private void playAlarm() {
    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

and here my **AlarmActivity.java**

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);

    playAlarm();
}

private void playAlarm() {
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),
            R.raw.intruder_alarm);
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
}
public void dismissAlarm(View view) {
    mMediaPlayer.release();
    this.finish();
}
```

Comment: In the `onDataChange()` method of `ParentActivity`, you update `latLng`, but the new value is not used anywhere.

Comment: owh I miss about that.Thanks for your mention sir.
So I need to use the 'latLng' instead of 'lat' and 'lng' at 'startGeofence()' sir ?

Or I need to change 'LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(...)' into 'latLng.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(...)' and for 'startGeofence()' I need to use FusedLocation provider location data (Parent user - position) ?